# They who can destroy the [splice], control the [splice]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splice) tag, by its description, is about the `splice` function in Linux:

> splice copies data between two file descriptors of which one must be a pipe. Effectively, this is equivalent to a userland function that performs a read/write operation to and from a kernel-owned buffer.

However, there's questions aplenty in this tag about e.g. array operations in various languages that probably don't even involve `splice` at any level. (They might, I don't know the internals of JavaScript and such very well.) Highly voted questions in the tag use it per its description, but more recent questions certainly do not.

Is this a sign that a cleanup is needed? Or should the tag itself be altered for the more intuitive use?

Comment: And whoever controls the [splice], controls the universe.

Comment: Isn't the splice function part of the linux kernel/glibc? Why a specific tag for this?

Comment: @Braiam I just found it like this, so your guess is as good as mine...

Comment: @Braiam I guess splicing is a type of concatenation commonly used, so...

Comment: +1 just for the Dune reference.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some background, based on [its tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/splice/info), the tag was created on June 7, 2011, and got [its excerpt at around the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6266131/revisions).

However, [the currently tagged questions posted in **2009**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsplice%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a2009&mixed=0) (no modification to the 'splice' tag) were:

- 2 JavaScript
- 1 Linux
- 1 Microsoft Word

And [in **2010**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsplice%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a2010&mixed=0) (again, no modification to the tag) were:

- 5 Linux
- 3 JavaScript
- 1 C++
- 1 ActionScript

[In 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Newest&q=%5bsplice%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a2020&mixed=0) though, most of the questions are about JavaScript and other programming languages, and Linux's is a minority.

I don't know what happened to the tag in the past (the tag's created date and its excerpt were later than the earliest question? Was there a merge?), but considering it has been used both for Linux and JavaScript questions since the beginning, I'd prefer to generalize the tag if possible, otherwise clean-up (if there's a specific quirk on Linux's `splice`), or else burninate.

Comment: Linux's `splice` is a function for moving data between file descriptors, while JS and other programming languages have `splice` functions as array operations (splice data from one array into the middle of another.) They should probably be different tags if, you know, tags are supposed to mean something.

Answer (score 2):

As a Javascript programmer who knows absolutely nothing about Linux, I think this tag is ambiguous. Since I don't know anything about Linux, which is supposedly its intended use, I can't say whether or not it should be burninated, but if not it should definitely be made less ambiguous.

As a Javascript programmer, when I see `splice`, I think of the [`splice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method for Javascript arrays, so if I hade a question about that method, I would be tempted to use the [splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/splice) tag. The tag wiki doesn't really help in telling me not to, since I don't really understand what it means.

If I saw it just like that without being told what it's referring to, I could probably guess that it's doesn't refer to the Javascript `splice()` method since the Javascript method doesn't copy data between files, but the rest of the tag wiki tells me absolutely nothing (What's a pipe? What's a userland function?). I could never guess it has to do with Linux. [The complete tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/splice/info) does mention Linux, but people rarely read that, and even if they did, it never mentions explicitly that `splice` is a Linux function.

And I can't blame Javascript beginners for using it to refer to the Javascript method, since some of them might think that the tag wiki is referring to Javascript concepts that they haven't seen yet. Even people like me who have a bit more experience in Javascript (but no experience in Linux) might still use it, since they might just ignore the tag wiki since they don't understand it.

So whether or not it should be burninated is up to people who know Linux, but I think that if it shouldn't be burninated, then at the very least the tag wiki should be rewritten to be understandable even to people who don't know Linux. Maybe it should even be renamed to something like [linux-splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-splice) to make it completely obvious that it's about Linux and not Javascript. Or maybe the intent of the tag should be changed so that it refers to splicing in general, not just on Linux.

Comment: it's not just JS - about every language with arrays has an associated splice method

Comment: @c-x-berger I guess. But a large majority of the most recent [splice] questions are about Javascript, so that's the main problem. But yes, as I mentioned, if the intent of the tag should be changed, it should be to refer to splicing in general.